# DataTables (serverSide) OK on first request, fails with "[Object object"] in request when searching or reordering

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask, datatables

Using DataTables jQuery plugin with serverSide = true (example here is small, but ultimately we want to handle large number of records). On initial request (first page load) everything works OK. DataTable looks great and it contains the expected data.

**Request info**

```
Request method = GET
Request args = ImmutableMultiDict([('draw', u'1'), ('columns[0][data]', u'client_user_id'), ('columns[1][name]', u''), ('columns[5][searchable]', u'true'), ('columns[5][name]', u''), ('columns[4][search][regex]', u'false'), ('columns[1][orderable]', u'true'), ('columns[4][orderable]', u'true'), ('columns[5][orderable]', u'true'), ('columns[2][orderable]', u'true'), ('columns[4][name]', u''), ('order[0][dir]', u'asc'), ('columns[1][search][regex]', u'false'), ('columns[3][name]', u''), ('columns[0][search][value]', u''), ('columns[2][searchable]', u'true'), ('columns[3][search][regex]', u'false'), ('extra_search', u'test'), ('columns[0][search][regex]', u'false'), ('columns[5][data]', u'last_login'), ('start', u'0'), ('columns[4][searchable]', u'true'), ('columns[0][searchable]', u'true'), ('columns[5][search][value]', u''), ('columns[3][searchable]', u'true'), ('columns[2][search][value]', u''), ('columns[2][search][regex]', u'false'), ('columns[1][data]', u'status'), ('columns[1][searchable]', u'true'), ('columns[5][search][regex]', u'false'), ('columns[0][orderable]', u'true'), ('columns[4][data]', u'client_id'), ('columns[0][name]', u''), ('columns[2][data]', u'lastname'), ('columns[3][data]', u'email_address'), ('search[value]', u''), ('columns[3][orderable]', u'true'), ('_', u'1484145221101'), ('columns[4][search][value]', u''), ('search[regex]', u'false'), ('columns[1][search][value]', u''), ('order[0][column]', u'0'), ('columns[2][name]', u''), ('length', u'10'), ('columns[3][search][value]', u'')])
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2017 09:33:41] "GET /client/rou/ajax/mwe?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=client_user_id&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=status&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=lastname&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=email_address&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=client_id&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=last_login&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&extra_search=test&_=1484145221101 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

...and data is returned from the server. However any interaction with the DataTable (e.g., clicking column heading to sort result, or typing in the search box) and subsequent ajax requests look like this:

**Request info when attempting search or sort**

```
Request method = GET
Request args = ImmutableMultiDict([('[object Object]', u''), ('_', u'1484145221102')])
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2017 09:33:46] "GET /client/rou/ajax/mwe?[object%20Object]&_=1484145221102 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Why in the first case do we get all the parameters OK, and in the second case we get [Object object]? What changes are needed so that DataTables makes valid requests?

**Python (using Flask)**

```
@blueprint.route('/rou/ajax/mwe', methods=("GET", "POST"))
def b_ajax_mwe():

    error = False
    error_text = None
    data = []

    print("Request method = {}".format(request.method))
    print("Request args = {}".format(request.args))
    draw = request.args.get('draw') or 1

    try:
        # Yes, I know this always returns same result... for now
        # once we have request from DataTable that's not "[Object object]"
        # we will modify to return data based on request
        query = ClientUser.query \
            .filter(ClientUser.client_id == 2) \
            .limit(10) \
            .all()

        data = [{'client_user_id': cu.client_user_id,
                 'status': cu.status,
                 'email_address': cu.email_address,
                 'lastname': cu.lastname,
                 'client_id': cu.client_id,
                 'last_login': cu.last_login} for cu in query]

    except Exception, err:
        error = True
        error_text = str(err)

    rows = ClientUser.query.count()

    result = {'draw': draw,
              'recordsTotal': rows,
              'recordsFiltered': len(data),
              'data': data}

    if error:
        result['error'] = error_text

    return jsonify(result)
```

**HTML (in head)**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.13/datatables.min.css"/>
```

**HTML (in body)**

```
<table class="table display" id="mwe_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User ID</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Client ID</th>
            <th>Last login</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.13/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

(jQuery 1.11 loaded before stuff from DataTables CDN, above)

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#mwe_table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/client/rou/ajax/mwe',
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "client_user_id" },
            { "data": "status" },
            { "data": "lastname" },
            { "data": "email_address" },
            { "data": "client_id" },
            { "data": "last_login" }
        ]
    });
});
```

No errors are reported in JavaScript console.

Comment: This probably won't solve your problem, but `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered` should probably be the same in this case.  Per the documentation, `recordsFiltered` should be `the total number of records after filtering has been applied - not just the number of records being returned for this page of data`

Comment: Understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce using the specified parameters, but think that I may have a workaround anyhow. You can explicitly tell DataTables how to serialize the request data.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#mwe_table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '/client/rou/ajax/mwe',
            data: function (d) {
                console.log(d); // display all properties to console
                return jQuery.param({
                    start: d.start,
                    length: d.length,
                    orderColumn: d.order[0].column,
                    orderDir: d.order[0].dir,
                    draw: d.draw
                });
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "client_user_id" },
            { "data": "status" },
            { "data": "lastname" },
            { "data": "email_address" },
            { "data": "client_id" },
            { "data": "last_login" }
        ]
    });
});
```

Notice that I am selectively sending some parameters by serializing a JavaScript object into `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` using `jQuery.param()`.  For simplicity, the JavaScript object only has simple properties and no nested objects or arrays.  The call to `jQuery.param()` is probably unnecessary, but I left it in to be explicit.